# What is this notation for a function? I've never seen it written like this before.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, notation

What does this mean? 
$$ f=\{ (x,y): y= x+2 \}$$

I don't understand what "$(x,y):$" means in regard to the problem. Also why is the $y$ inside of the $f(x)$ function. Isn't it supposed to be outside?

Comment: The RHS is the graph of the function $f$ defined by $f(x)=x+2$. This is usually considered as different to the function $f$ itself. However, in ZF set theory, where everything is set, a function is defined as a graph. It would help if you could provide the context where you have seen this.

Comment: Sat math 2 practice test

Comment: One more comment. $(x,y):$ means the points $(x,y)$ such that whatever follows the ":" is true.

Comment: @Taladris Some prefer to define functions as triples $(f,A,B)$ where $f\subset A\times B$ is a functional relation (i.e. satisfies vertical line test or is well-defined) such that $\pi_1 f=A$, so that the domain and codomain are specified.  To be fair, specifying $A$ is not necessary because $\pi_1 f=A$, but the codomain does need to be specified.

Comment: While this is a valid way of expression a function, it is far from usual practice.

Comment: a function is a type of binary relation. see the formal definition  of binary relation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relations#Formal_definition

Answer (score 3):

If you would have the function (in your usual sense) $f(x) = x+2$, the set $f$ you described above would be precisely the *graph* of the function. In other words, instead of giving you the value of $f(x)$ for each $x$ (which is indicated by the equality $f(x) = x+2$), you are being given the set of points in the plane which are on its graph, that is, the couples $(x,y)$ such that $y = f(x)$ (i.e. $y=x+2$).

Hope that helps,

Comment: Where can I find more problems like this. I'm studying for the Sat math 2 test and this showed up with little explanation.

Comment: @Elle : I wouldn't exactly call this a problem, it's all about understanding the definition...

Answer (score 1):

Everything is a set. Particularly, a function itself is a set. When we write $$f: A \to B$$
we have that $f \subseteq A \times B$, where $\times$ denotes the cartesian product of $A$ and $B$. But, to say that $f$ is a function, it must satisfy the following condition: $$\forall \ x \in A ~((x,y),(x,z)\in f \implies y = z)$$
This is just saying that the function is *well-defined*. Since the element in the second entry of the ordered pair is uniquely defined for $x \in A$, we call that element $f(x)$. In details, that set $f$ is the graph of the function itself.

Comment: It is also worth noting that saying that "$f$ is a function from $A$ to $B$" implies that $f$ also has the property that $\forall x\in A \exists y\in B ((x,y)\in f)$.  Of course, well-definedness is sufficient to say that $f$ is a function from *some* domain to *some* codomain.

Comment: @Ivo Terek : "Everything is a set" is a bit of an over-statement, but it is a nice saying... (In fact, the class of all sets is not a set, that's what I meant.) Although in set theory all constructions are built out of sets ; numbers, functions, operations, types of spaces (topological/vector/measure spaces) and so on.

Comment: I figured someone might say something about it. I did not worry about this, bearing in mind that this was a rather basic question. If OP has interest in set theory, this is a good think to look a bit after (;